# Cant access setup(or any files) of magento2 in browser

Tags: magento2, error, permissions

Installed **lamp** on **centos 7**.
Moved files to `/var/www/html/`

**When I chmod 655** magento directory I can see apache welcome screen, but when i try `IP_addr/index.php` gives:

> "You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server."

**When I chmod 755** magento directory I can see only 500 error.

**When I follow magento permision setting** I can see only 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the Magento file system owner, owner of the install dir -  chown -R : .

Comment: Isn't file system owner also automaticaly owner of install dir, or have i mixed it up? I created  user called **magento** as owner of /var/www/html

Comment: Follow the instructions on this page https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: I followed those instructioins. But perhaps I am confused whot is magento file system owner, since i am new to this. Is it root or the one I asigned to apache dir with chown.

Comment: Basically you need to create new user and add it to the web server role then execute EVERY magento related command with that user